# React: Fade slideshow not working. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, slideshow

I am getting an error while trying to implement the Fade slideshow. The required image is:
[image]

The required codes are:
Home.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Header from '../Header/Header';
import Slideshow from '../Slideshow/Slideshow';


class Home extends Component{
        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    <Header/>
                    <Slideshow/>
                </div>
            )

        }
};

export default Home;
```

Slideshow.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Fade } from 'react-slideshow-image';
const images = [
  'https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/al-pacino-sits-in-a-chair-in-a-scene-from-the-film-the-godfather-part-picture-id159840433?s=2048x2048',
  'https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/al-pacino-us-actor-sitting-in-an-armchair-in-a-publicity-still-issued-picture-id139630136?s=2048x2048'
];

const Slideshow = () => {
    return (
        <Fade
          images={images}
          duration="5000"
          transitionDuration="1000"/>
       )
    }

export default Slideshow;
```

Please tell me how to fix it.

Comment: I did not find [images] prop in Fade component. As fa I as understand, Fade component expects children. Please, loot at the docs https://react-slideshow.herokuapp.com/fade-effect

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your images as `children` to `Fade` component not `props`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Fade } from 'react-slideshow-image';
const images = [
  'https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/al-pacino-sits-in-a-chair-in-a-scene-from-the-film-the-godfather-part-picture-id159840433?s=2048x2048',
  'https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/al-pacino-us-actor-sitting-in-an-armchair-in-a-publicity-still-issued-picture-id139630136?s=2048x2048'
];

const Slideshow = () => {
    return (
        <Fade>
          // first child
          <div className="each-fade">
            <div className="image-container">
             <img src={images[0]} />
            </div>
            <h2>First Slide</h2>
          </div>
          // second child
          <div className="each-fade">
            <div className="image-container">
              <img src={images[1]} />
            </div>
            <h2>Second Slide</h2>
          </div>
       </Fade>
     )
}

export default Slideshow;
```